# The use of " of "

Tags: meaning, grammar

1. He was one of the original developers of the Unix version of the Netscape browser.
2. He was one of the original developers of the Netscape browser  of the Unix
   version.

What is the difference? And what are their  respective meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is not correct. It doesn't specify what the Unix version is a version of.

The original sentence sounds odd because there are three instances of the word "of."

I want to draw a Venn diagram here, as there is a nested relationship of the three clauses. Each one is a subset of the next one.

The first sentence means: among all versions of Netscape there is a Unix version; among all developers of that version, he was one.

There might have been Windows or Mac OS versions of Netscape but he wasn't one of the developers of them.

The second sentence means:  there was a Unix version of some unspecified thing, which had a Netscape browser that he was one of the developers of.

I don't think that is right.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is the order of the words.  They read the same to me.

Comment: They mean entirely different things, and as Chellspecker points out, the second doesn't really make sense.